# ¿Cómo puedo agregar objetos de Interfaz Gráfica (Swing) a un Array?

Tags: java, java-swing

La duda viene de aquí:

Estoy practicando interfaces gráficas en java, lo que pasa es que estoy agregando elemento por elemento al `JFrame`. Lo que quiero es agregar todos los objetos creados`(JButton, JLabel, JRadioButton, etc...)` a un `array` para así agregarlos con un ciclo iterativo `foreach.`

Ejemplo de lo que no quiero hacer :

```
JButton jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4, jb5, jb6;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Programa de interfaz");
frame.add(jb1);
frame.add(jb2);
frame.add(jb3);
frame.add(jb4);
frame.add(jb5);
```

Obviamente quisiera reducir ese código, porque son mas de 30 lineas de elementos como el ejemplo de arriba.

Comment: Puedes crear un `array` de tipo `Component` y añadir los elementos que desee para luego iterar e ir añadiendo a `JFrame` aunque en la practica hará los mismas operaciones al agregar al `array` que al agregar directamente al `JFrame`

Comment: Muchas gracias Joel intentare el metodo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes almacenar todos los objetos creados (`JButton`, `JLabel`, `JComboBox`, ...) en un arreglo de tipo `Component`, y utilizar este en el `foreach`